# TempData currently unable to handle this request

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, tempdata

How can I fix TempData is not working, page redirects to `localhost is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500`

What I want to achieve is to create a form that accepts model, and can add multiple data, I want to store the temporary list of model to the `TempData` before inserting it all to database and I got stuck from this issue. How can I possibly fix this? Am I missing something?

Here is my `Startup.cs` code:

```
// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    //some code here

    //services.AddMvc();
    services.AddMvc().AddSessionStateTempDataProvider();
    services.AddSession();
}

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    //some code here

    app.UseSession();

    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
}
```

Controller code:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult Create1(BooksViewModel vmodel, Books books)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //some code here

        TempData["BooksViewModel"] = books;

        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Entry));
    }
    return View();
}

public IActionResult Entry()
{
    BooksViewModel vmodel = (BooksViewModel)TempData["BooksViewModel"];
    List<BooksViewModel> list = new List<BooksViewModel>();
    list = (List<BooksViewModel>)TempData["BooksViewModelList"];
    if (vmodel != null)
    {
        //some code here
    }
    TempData["BooksViewModelList"] = list;
    return View(list);
}
```

Entry.cshtml code:

```
  @model IEnumerable<QnE_Accounting.Models.TransactionsViewModel.BooksViewModel>

<p>
    <a asp-action="Create">Create New</a>
</p>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
              //some code here
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            //some code here
            <td>
                <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Edit</a> |
                <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Details</a> |
                <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Delete</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: can you show us the view associated with or a repository with your project?

Comment: @mvermef, already updated the code sir

Comment: @mvermef, i dont konw if my view is working properly because I got stuck in this current issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

500 Errors always comes with the exception details, that should tell you what is wrong! So inspect the exception/inner exception to see why your code is crashing. I would also suggest you to use visual studio breakpoints and inspect the C# expressions (your code) to see it has the values as expected.

Regarding TempData, In Asp.Net core, you cannot pass complex types in TempData. You can pass simple types like `string`, `int`, `Guid` etc. This is by design.

If you absolutely want to pass a complex type object between 2 action methods, you have a few options

**1) Serialize your object to a string and pass that.**

```
var booksString = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(books);
TempData["books"] = booksString;
return RedirectToAction("Entry");
```

and in your `Entry` action, you will read from TempData and deserialize the string back to your object.

```
public IActionResult Entry()
{
    var tempDataStr = TempData["books"] as string;
    // De serialize the string to object
    var books = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Books>(tempDataStr);
    // Use books
    // to do : return something
}
```

**2) Persist the data and read it again.**
You can store the data somewhere and read it again. Here are 2 options to consider.

- Session state
- Database table

Comment: best answer to your question.